# Fastest way to use isin in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv with ID columns, where the IDs in the first csv are a subset of the IDs in the second csv. In order to save space, after reading in the first csv, I'm trying to read in only the rows in the second csv that appear in the first csv like so:

```
chunker = pd.read_csv(t_path)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in chunker:
    # keep_ids is a series of ids from previous table
    temp = chunk[chunk['Id'].isin(keep_ids)]
    df = df.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
df.reset_index()
```

The files that I'm dealing with are as large as 30 gigs so this can be a tad slow. Is there a quicker way to find the proper id, possibly using indexes?

Edit 1: Could it be fast to set the index of the chunk equal to the id column and then only keep rows that successfully merge with keep_ids?

Comment: Did you look at [`usecols`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#filtering-columns-usecols)?

Comment: I'm looking to select rows not columns, so it didn't seem like that would help.

Comment: Your question says "I'm trying to read in only the columns in the second csv that appear in the first csv".  If that's not what you mean, you should edit that.

Comment: What type is `keep_ids`?  If it's a Series/DataFrame, try converting to a list.

Comment: keep_ids is a series. I'll try to use a list instead. Is that really faster? @BrenBarn thanks for pointing that out, made changes.

Comment: Actually may not be faster - the test I was playing around with was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that :

```
chunker = pd.read_csv(t_path, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
df = pd.concat(chunk[chunk['Id'].isin(keep_ids) for chunk in chunker ])
```

Comment: Thanks. I think most of the slowdown though is in the searching for Ids. Wondering if isin is the fastest way to perform this search or if I can do something with indexes...